# php vs txt display - courier and times

Tags: php, text, unicode, encoding

Why is it when I upload a plain text file to a server, it displays (in Safari) using the courier font, and when I output from a php it shows as Times?

Comment: Check the "fonts" preferences of your browser.

Comment: It's browser related issue, nothing to do with PHP, unicode and encoding. `Text` does not have "property" `Font`. It's just `text`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plain text is plain text. It carries no formatting information of its own, and the browsers will decide how to display it.  Displaying a file directly, the web server will supply it with a mime type `text/plain`. This will often instruct the browser to use a fixed width font (Courier). But if you output it with PHP, the server is sending it as `text/html` (HTML) and the browser is using its default font for HTML (Times, in your case).

For the plain text, you don't have any control over how the end user's browser will render it. That setting is entirely up to browser defaults or user preferences.  Of course, you can influence how it is displayed as HTML when output by PHP with CSS declarations.

Comment: Thank, for my purposes I simply renamed my plain text .txt file as a .html

Answer (score 2):

That's specified by your browser. You can setup that within your browsers settings if you prefer other fonts. What you describe is a common setup.

The server is only specifying the so called content-type, `text/plain` for the text-file, `text/html` for the php page.

The user uses the browser to display them accordingly, like the font and it's size. If you add CSS to your html output and the user allows your website to provide CSS for displaying purposes (which is quite common as well), then the CSS style information will be used which could change the font and size.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but when your answer had only the first paragraph it didn't really answer the question which is "why does the same text have a different font if it's generated with PHP".

Comment: @Juhana: Well I was actually asking that to the one who downvoted out of curiosity.

Comment: Right, and I answered with what I believe is the reason the downvoter did it.

Comment: @Juhana: Yeah thanks for your feedback, but apparently the first paragraph pretty well describes why this does happen. The content-type itself is pretty much internal tech-bla. The most important part is how the browser is configured for the appearance of any document it renders.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP didn't know that the document type is different :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because of `Content-type` HTTP header.
It's `text/plain` in case of txt file and `text/html` with php

Web-server do check mime-type of the file (judging by extension) and send appropriate header.